# as.glht: Cannot convert an object of class ‘list’ to a ‘glht’ object

Tags: r

I have the following R code:

```
# load data
df = read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZeningQu/fa4dbe5a1e82b71f7ebf6e35ec56b72b/raw/3072410fb0ea900fae4dff9cb68c5a2e2a2bab2f/bookflights.csv")
View(df)
df$Subject = factor(df$Subject) # convert to nominal factor
df$International = factor(df$International) # convert to nominal factor
df$Ease = ordered(df$Ease) # convert to ordinal factor

# analyze Ease Likert ratings on Website * International with ordinal logistic regression
library(MASS) # for polr
library(car) # for Anova
# set sum-to-zero contrasts for the Anova call
contrasts(df$Website) <- "contr.sum"
contrasts(df$International) <- "contr.sum"
m = polr(Ease ~ Website * International, data=df, Hess=TRUE) # ordinal logistic
Anova(m, type=3) 

# post hoc pairwise comparisons 
library(multcomp)
library(lsmeans) # equivalent way using lsmeans, pairs, and as.glht
summary(as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International))),
        test=adjusted(type="none"))
```

Error:

```
Error in as.glht.default(pairs(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International))) : 
  Cannot convert an object of class ‘list’ to a ‘glht’ object
```

I know this is an error thrown by `as.glht`: https://github.com/cran/emmeans/blob/master/R/glht-support.R#L169
But what can I do to convert `pairs` to `glht`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand why this happened. The call:

```
lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International)
```

is actually shorthand for a two-step operation:

```
lsm <- lsmeans(m, ~ Website * International)
prs <- pairs(lsm)
```

and the result is a list of two `emmGrid` objects, `lsm` and `prs`.

What you coded was `as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International)))`, and the inside part, `pairs(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International))` is already overkill because it generates pairwise comparisons of *each element* of the results. So you get a list consisting of pairwise comparisons of the LS means (which is what you probably want), and pairwise comparisons of the pairwise comparisons (which is probably not what you want).

Here are two ways to get the results you want. One is to omit the l.h.s. of the formula...

```
as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, ~ Website * International)))
```

the other is to omit `pairs()` and call for the part of the results you want...

```
as.glht(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International)[[2]])
```

One of my biggest regrets as developer of **lsmeans/emmeans** is that darned two-sided formula interface. It has created a lot of confusion and a lot of questions like this one. But I am doomed to keep it available because people are in such a hurry to get all the results they want in one step instead of two. The price of convenience is quite steep.

Comment: BTW, you may be interested in looking at more restricted sets of comparisons, e.g., `as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, ~ Website | International)))` and `as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, ~ International | Website)))`. Or to put all; the restricted comparisons in one class for multiplicity adjustment, `as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, ~ Website | International)), by = NULL)` etc.

Comment: Thank you @rvl Yes I'm actually interested in comparing the `International` conditions given `Website`. I didn't know I could do `summary(as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, ~ International | Website))),
        test=adjusted(type="holm"))`! I was generating all the possible pairs and then manually pick the p-values of the pairs I'm interested in and adjust for multiple comparisons like `p.adjust(c(1.44e-10, 1.35e-12, 0.474476 ), method="holm")`. Your suggestions are much cleaner!

Comment: Note, you don’t really need to use glht either. Just `test(pairs(...), adjust = “holm”)` will do the same thing. See some of the vignettes in the **emmeans** package.

Comment: @rlv `summary(as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, ~ International | Website))), test=adjusted(type="holm"))` gives exactly the same p-values as unadjusted `summary(as.glht(pairs(lsmeans(m, ~ International | Website))), test=adjusted(type="none"))`. Is this expected?

Comment: It is if there is only one test — because then there is no multiplicity!

Comment: I think the test spec needs to go one level outside of the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

`as.glht` requires an object of class `emmGrid or emm_list`, so lets check you data:

```
> class(pairs(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International)))
[1] "list"
```

Its not of correct class, so lets try converting it

```
> class(lsmeans:::as.emm_list(pairs(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International))))
[1] "emm_list" "list"
```

It appears as it has worked, so plug it back in:

```
> summary(as.glht(lsmeans:::as.emm_list(pairs(lsmeans(m, pairwise ~ Website * International)))),
+         test=adjusted(type="none"))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Linear Hypotheses:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Expedia,0 - Orbitz,0 == 0       -2.1442     0.2619  -8.189 2.22e-16 ***
Expedia,0 - Priceline,0 == 0    -0.9351     0.2537  -3.686 0.000228 ***
Expedia,0 - Expedia,1 == 0      -1.6477     0.2570  -6.411 1.44e-10 ***
Expedia,0 - Orbitz,1 == 0       -0.3217     0.2490  -1.292 0.196380    
Expedia,0 - Priceline,1 == 0    -0.7563     0.2517  -3.004 0.002663 ** 
Orbitz,0 - Priceline,0 == 0      1.2091     0.2555   4.732 2.22e-06 ***
Orbitz,0 - Expedia,1 == 0        0.4965     0.2505   1.982 0.047498 *  
Orbitz,0 - Orbitz,1 == 0         1.8225     0.2571   7.089 1.35e-12 ***
Orbitz,0 - Priceline,1 == 0      1.3879     0.2546   5.452 4.99e-08 ***
Priceline,0 - Expedia,1 == 0    -0.7126     0.2518  -2.830 0.004659 ** 
Priceline,0 - Orbitz,1 == 0      0.6134     0.2497   2.457 0.014023 *  
Priceline,0 - Priceline,1 == 0   0.1789     0.2501   0.715 0.474476    
Expedia,1 - Orbitz,1 == 0        1.3260     0.2524   5.254 1.49e-07 ***
Expedia,1 - Priceline,1 == 0     0.8914     0.2506   3.557 0.000375 ***
Orbitz,1 - Priceline,1 == 0     -0.4345     0.2477  -1.754 0.079408 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- none method)
```